# Trouble visualizing a subset of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: number-theory, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I have the following problem:

Fix $ C>0 $.

I want to figure out as much as possible about the following set
\begin{equation}\label{key}
S= \left  \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : \exists m \in \mathbb{N}:   \left| \dfrac{n}{Cm} -1  \right| < \dfrac{1}{2m}  \right \} 
\end{equation}

I am looking for any particular way to visualise this set, in particular as $m \to \infty$.

I want to say that it is the set of integers that are divisible by $C$, but I am not quite sure. More specifically, I suspect that the relative density of $S$ to $\mathbb{N}$ is $1/C$, but I am not sure if this is true or how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality
$$\left| \frac{n}{Cm} - 1 \right| < \frac{1}{2m}$$ can be multiplied by $m$ to get
$$\left| \frac{n}{C} - m \right| < \frac{1}{2}$$
Which defines the nearest integer from $n/C$. Such an integer $m$ exists if and only if $n/C$ is not a half-integer (i.e. an integer $+1/2$).

If $C$ is irrational, then $n/C$ is irrational and in particular it is not an half-integer. In such a case $S= \Bbb N$.

If $C$ is rational, things get more complicated. In any case you can write
$$S= \left\{ n \in \Bbb N : \frac{n}{C} + \frac{1}{2} \notin \Bbb N \right\}$$